# WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, microservices, azure-service-fabric

### Problem

I am trying to deploy the service fabric application from Visual Studio and Power Shell. It shows me the same error

## Error

> WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
> WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...

My service fabric cluster is in Azure with certificate security
I already went through many solutions available online but the issues remain.

Comment: Did you install the certificate on your local machine? Can you connect to the SF Explorer? Did you configure the (correct) publish profile in cloud.xml?

Comment: yes I connect to service fabric explorer and also install the certificate on my local machine

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? I have seen this issue when a corporate proxy interferes with traffic

Comment: If the issue is because of proxy, how do we go about resolving this? I mean where exactly should we be configuring the proxy settings in visual studio / azure service fabric SDK?